# System.InvalidCastException HResult=0x80004002 Message=Unable to cast COM

Tags: vb.net, outlook, casting, office-interop, office-automation

I am trying to read the sent items folder of my outlook, with the following code:

```
         Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

        Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 
        Dim moApp As Outlook.Application

        Dim moNS As Outlook.NameSpace

        moApp = New Outlook.Application

        moNS = moApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem

        oFolder = moNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)

        For Each i As Object In oFolder.Items
            If TypeOf i Is MailItem Then
                MessageBox.Show("From: " & i.To)
            End If
        Next
```

[Outlook folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okm4t.png)

outlook folders

when I try to read the information of the MailItem object I get the error

```
"System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Could not convert COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063034-0000-0000-C000-0000000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface is supported (0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
  Source=SendMail"
```

But when I try it with the inbox folder, it works without any problem.

I am also validated to receive a `MailItem` object.

Has this error happened to anyone else?

Comment: Dont cast, inspect all the types in that folder with your debugger, then ignore or cast appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore the problematic item in any low-level property explorer tool such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy. Is there any difference between other items in the folder? Is it a true mail item?

You may also try to use the late binding technology represented in .Net by reflection. The [Type.InvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=net-7.0) allows to get property value without casting objects.

Note, you can use the "is" and "as" operators in C#. See [How to: Programmatically Determine the Current Outlook Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx) for more information. If the `is` operator throws an exception you may try to use the `as` instead.

Also the Outlook object model provides the [MessageClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867813(v=office.15).aspx) property - a string representing the message class for the Outlook item. Under the hood the message class is used to identify what inspector to use in Outlook for displaying the item.